# Scite sends all characters including the characters I deleted

Tags: ruby, scite

I attempted to capture input using 'gets,' but it includes all characters, including those that I deleted. For instance, take a look at the following program.

```
puts "Enter your name : "
STDOUT.flush
name=gets
p name
```

When requesting input, the printed output includes the characters I entered, even those that I am in the process of deleting.

Here is the output you could notice.

```
>ruby hi.rb
Enter your  name : 
raja
"rajaagoa\n"
>Exit code: 0
```

I understand that 'gets' captures all the characters, leading to the current output. However, I would like to only display the characters I input. In the given example, if I enter 'raja,' I want only 'raja' to be printed but unfortunately it prints all the characters which I deleted while I input. Is there a way to accomplish this?

I also experimented with the code below, but it exhibited the same behavior.

```
page_name = ""
while (char = STDIN.getc) != "\n"
  page_name += char
end
```

Comment: What OS and terminal (emulator) do you use? Which keys do you press?

Comment: I utilize the Windows OS along with the Scite editor for my work. Interestingly, the functionality works seamlessly when I employ RubyMine. However, the issue arises when I use the Scite editor. Unfortunately, I distribute my Automation Software exclusively with the Scite editor since it is an open-source tool.

Comment: _"the issue arises when I use the Scite editor"_ – sounds like a bug with your editor.

Comment: You are right. I tried directly from command prompt, it works fine. I think the problem is with Scite editor.

Comment: You might want to rephrase the question accordingly. It's more like _"Scite sends all characters including the characters I deleted"_

Comment: SciTE is not Terminal based and captures user keystrokes ... how does it come that you expect from it to be able to edit your input line without you yourself coding what need to be done to the input key code stream in order to update the captured string in case of backspace or delete? It is not curses based input line ... just reporting the characters.AND also the key codes of the key strokes as characters. Notice: SciTE supports getting the key codes of pressed keys on the keyboard so you can utilize this to "edit" the string of received input ... This will solve your issue with SciTE.

Comment: Notice that SciTE Lua supports both: OnChar() and OnKey(). You need to use the OnKey() callback in order to be able to "edit" yourself programmatically received stream of user input key strokes from within the Lua code to arrive at a string like you will get from Terminal based line input on Return.

Comment: Probably the best solution would be to change the program logic ... else you need to code line input in style of the curses library in your SciTE Lua code.